# ajax success for loop to group or create results as array or string in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have an ajax which posts multiple variable to php. Now the return of course is multiple.

Let's say I send date_now.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "ajax/default_q.php",
  dataType: "json", 
  type: 'POST',
  data: {dtime: n},
```

Query on the Php side looks like this

```
$sql = "SELECT animal_id,FROM_UNIXTIME(microtime,' %M ') as microtimes,srp FROM shelter_code WHERE microtime BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day)) and 1480723199";
$res   = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['link'],$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $content[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($content);
```

As I understand it, this will return animal_id, microtimes and srp. Going back to ajax and this time on the success part.

```
success: function(result) {
    
    var arrayLength = result.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        var a = result[i].microtimes;
        var b = result[i].srp;
        var c = result[i].animal_id;

        
    }

    if (c == '99322904100382281') {var size="Large Size"; var prices = b; alert(size); alert(prices);}
```

If I alert a,b,c it alerts the correct data. By the way, data as seen below
[image]

And here's the Dataset I've been trying to populate

```
var salesChartData = {
      labels: a,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Large",
          fillColor: "rgb(255,40,40)",
          strokeColor: "rgb(255,40,40)",
          pointColor: "rgb(253,16,16)",
          pointStrokeColor: "#c1c7d1",
          pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
          pointHighlightStroke: "rgb(220,220,220)",
          data: b
        },
        {
          label: "Medium",
          fillColor: "rgba(60,141,188,0.9)",
          strokeColor: "rgba(60,141,188,0.8)",
          pointColor: "#3b8bba",
          pointStrokeColor: "rgba(60,141,188,1)",
          pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
          pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(60,141,188,1)",
          data: b
        }
      ]
    };
```

In the third picture if you notice I've been trying to give it an if else statement.

What I want to achieve it how can I group the december, price and animal id and novermber, price and animal id.

Ive tried but the result is shown below and I know somethings wrong

[image]

If you can see it shows November only and it treats the string as an array.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
success: function(result) {

var arrayLength = result.length;

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var a[i] = result[i].microtimes;
    var b[i] = result[i].srp;
    var c[i] = result[i].animal_id;

}
```